# Помогите в чем проблема

Tags: java

```
package MainClass;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Frame.Menu.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Chuffie");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root,358,397));
        primaryStage.show();


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);

    }

}
```

Ошибка : at MainClass.Main.start(Main.java:14)

Comment: У вас с названием *.fxml файла ничего не напутанно?

Comment: Приведите полный stacktrace, предположу, что к ресурсу нужно обратиться как: getClass().getResource("/Frame.Menu.fxml")

Comment: Проблема в заголовке вопроса. Как другие страждущие смогут понять, о чем внутри речь?

Comment: попробуй в начале метода start обратится через super.

Comment: Это правильный импорт